# Why my program stops in waitpid() without any error information?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a simplified shell. It uses `waitpid()` to wait for the child process to terminate. But it always stops in the function `waitpid()`.

This is my source code:

```
if(fundex >= 0){
  cmd_table[fundex].fun(tokens);
} else {
  /* REPLACE this to run commands as programs. */
    pid_t cpid = fork();

    if(cpid == -1)
            printf(" --- fork error! ---");
    else if(cpid == 0){    /* exxcuted by child */

        signal(SIGINT,SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGQUIT,SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTTOU,SIG_DFL);

        pid_t pid = getpid();
        pid_t pgid = getpgid(pid);

        if(pgid == shell_pgid)
                printf("\n -- right id -- ");

        printf(" \n--pid = %d --",pid);
        printf(" \n--pgid = %d --",pgid);

        setpgid(pid,pid);
        printf("\n--pgrp is set--");        

        pid_t newPgid = getpgid(pid);
        printf(" newPgid is gotten");

        printf("\n");

        printf(" \n--new pgid = %d --",newPgid);

        tcsetpgrp(0,newPgid);

        io_redirect(tokens);

        execution(tokens);

        }
        else{   /* executed by parent */
            printf(" \n--wating --");

            waitpid(cpid,NULL,0);
            tcsetpgrp(0,shell_pgid);
        }
    }
```

This is what gdb told me:

```
Starting program: /home/yanghao/cs162/ta/hw1/yhshell 
0: ls


 -- right id --  
--pid = 76373 -- 
--pgid = 76372 --
--pgrp is set-- newPgid is gotten
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7ac8687 in __GI___waitpid (pid=76373, stat_loc=0x0, options=0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
30    return SYSCALL_CANCEL (wait4, pid, stat_loc, options, NULL);
```

This is what `../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30` contains:

```
return SYSCALL_CANCEL (wait4, pid, stat_loc, options, NULL);
```

I'm using glibc-2.30 for my gdb, my operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

So it seems that there is some error with `SYSCALL_CANCEL`. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Ok, so the _parent process blocks_  on `waitpid(cpid, NULL, 0)` call? Does the child every exit? There is `exeuction(tokens)` call, what if you would substitute that `execution` for `exit(1)` ? Would `waitpid` unblock then? Because output is usually line buffered, to see it add a newline in `printf(" \n--wating --");`

Comment: It doesn't stop with waitpid() because it's never called. Check again messages you printf(). Also take another look at waitpid(2) for its correct usage.

Comment: This "*warning: Source file is more recent than executable.*" looks fishy. Are you sure you recompiled everything before you ran the program?

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks, after I check my 'printf', it turns out that it's my child process blocks on 'tcsetpgrp'...

Comment: @alk I guess that warning is because I changed source path of gdb ....

Comment: when calling the `get...()` and/or the `tcget...()` functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Otherwise any failure of those operations will be unnoticed in your program

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

The problem is that  I can't see `printf(" \n--new pgid = %d --",newPgid);` and `printf(" \n--wating --");`, because I didn't add newline to buffer `stdout`.

Anyways, my process is blocked on io_redirect, because my input generate memory access violation in `io_redirect`.

There isn't any input check in my fool definition of `io_direct`.